# Google OAUTH2 no refresh_token received

Tags: ember.js, google-oauth, ember-simple-auth, refresh-token, torii

I am using emberjs and i could get this response from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

```
{
 "access_token": "snip",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "id_token": "snip"
}
```

but i am never getting refresh token not even on first authentication. I am stuck with it for hours can anyone help me

My request params

```
code:4/6_Rm706y9Y4vAFSiR6BAF6GXEIQgG8IKkk_8JHSC7sU
redirect_uri:http://localhost:8080/app
client_id:****************
client_secret:****************
scope: null
grant_type:authorization_code
access_type:offline
approval_prompt:force
```

Comment: Heu @NaveenStuns, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Matt no I tried for a bit and I gave up